# Ionic prevent add data if firebase data is 0

Tags: node.js, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm making an Ionic stock inventory application. In my **available stocks** page, I'm tracking user data like this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let stock of stocks | async" class="item item-trns text-center"
    (click)="showOptions(stock, stock.$key)">
      <strong><h2>{{ stock.name }}</h2></strong>
      <p>Date added: {{stock.date}}</p>
      <p>Quantity in stock: {{stock.actualq-stock.sold}}</p>
      <p>Sold: {{stock.sold}}</p>
```

This shows a list of all the stocks from my firebase backend.

```
showOptions(stock, stock.$key)
```

gives the options to sell the particular item.

As you can see, quantity remaining in stock is calculated as

```
Quantity in stock: {{stock.actualq-stock.sold}}
```

that is, the actual quantity minus the quantity already sold.

**My problem:**
When adding sales, how do I prevent a user from adding a sale value that is larger than the quantity already available in stock? This would lead to a negative quantity value remaining in stock.

I've tried to use form validation but I just can't figure out how to check if the data entered will be larger than the stock available in my firebase backend.

Is there a way to disable the list options if {{stock.actualq-stock.sold}} is 0?

Here's my sell function:

```
addSale(id,saledate,salequantity,buyingprice,sellingprice,sale,profit,saletotal) {
    if(id) {
      this.stocks.update(id, {
        saledate: saledate,
        salequantity: salequantity,
        buyingprice: buyingprice,
        sellingprice: sellingprice,
        sale: true,
        profit: (sellingprice-buyingprice)*salequantity,
        saletotal: (salequantity*sellingprice),

      }).then( newSale => {
            this.toast.show('Data updated', '5000', 'center').subscribe(
              toast => {
                this.navCtrl.pop();
              }
            );
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            this.toast.show(e, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
              toast => {
                console.log(toast);
              }
            );
          });
```

All this does is it updates the path for the specific item in stock being sold and adds the nodes above to reflect that a sale been added on the item.

Comment: can you post your sell function?

Comment: @Hareesh I've edited the question to include the sell function

Comment: where you calling this function `addSale()` in template?. isn't it inside `ion-item`?

Comment: @Hareesh I'm calling it in template from a button like this: `<button id="addSale-button" ion-button clear color="balanced" block large (click)="addSale(product.id, product.saledate, product.salequantity, product.buyingprice, product.sellingprice, product.sale)" [disabled]="!saleForm.valid">
<ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon></button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you have the stock id to update. So before updating get the current data and check the stock in hand and perform update. Try

```
addSale(id,saledate,salequantity,buyingprice,sellingprice,sale,profit,saletotal) {
    if(id) {
        this.db.object('stocks/'+id).snapshotChanges().subscribe(action => {
           console.log(action.payload.val());
           let stockInHand = action.payload.val().actualq-action.payload.val().sold;
           //check if salequantity is lessthan or equal to stockInHand
           if(salequantity <= stockInHand){
               //perform update
           }else{
               //toast no stock available 
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. that approach makes a lot of sense, seems it could work. but I'm using angularfire2-offline and getting the error 'snapshotChanges' does not exist on type 'AfoObjectObservable<any>' when I replace `db.object` with `afoDatabase.object`. If I leave it as `db.object` I get the error Property 'db' does not exit on type 'myPage'.

Comment: even after switching to using af2, I'm still getting the error snapshotChanges() does not exist on type FirebaseObjectObservable<any>

Comment: I am not sure about `angularfire2-offline`. Here `db` i mean this `constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase)` . It will work with `FirebaseObjectObservable` chek this [link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md#retrieving-the-snapshot). If its not may be you are using an older version on af2, please specify your version

Comment: was able to make it work with a few changes. thanks!!